# uncaught define error any solutions for this?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Speed typing game</title>
    <script src="speed.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="speed.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Start game!" class="button">
    <div class="letter">A</div>
    <div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

how i solve this error it's at line 59 so you know where it is do i have to give a value to the letter i tried that but it didn't work?

`speed.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined at speed.js:59`

```js
let max=10
var letter= 'A'
let color="purple"
let right='right'
var top='top'
var startbutton=document.querySelector('input[type=button]')
    
    
startbutton.addEventListener("click",startgame)
// start the game with a random number,hide the button//
function startgame() {
        startbutton.classList.add("hidden")
        let interval = 1000
        setInterval(createNewLetter,interval);
}

/*generate random number between 1-8 */
function randomNumber(min,max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * ( max+ 1))
}

    // generate a random letter //
    function randomLetter() {
     //generam un cod Ascii intre 65('A') si 90('Z') //
            let codeofA= "A".charCodeAt(0);
     let codeofZ= "Z".charCodeAt(0)       
     let randomCode= randomNumber(codeofA, codeofZ);
            // convertim codul ascii in caracterul asociat lui //
            return String.fromCharCode(randomCode)
    
    }
    
    // genereaza o culoare aleatorie //
     function randomColor() {
             let red = randomNumber(0,255)
             let green = randomNumber(0,255)
             let blue= randomNumber(0,255)
             return 'rgb(${red},${green},${blue})'
     }
     // genereaza o pozitie aleatorie intre 0% si 90% //
     function randomPosition() {
             let position = randomNumber(0,90)
             return '${position}%'
     }
     // creaza un nou element div cu o litera aleatorie //
     // adaugarea elementului in html//
     function createNewLetter() {
             let letter = randomLetter()
             let color= randomColor()
             let top = randomPosition()
             let right= randomPosition()
     }
     // cream un nou element div //
     let div = document.createElement("div")
     // adaugam o clasa letter //
     div.classList.add("letter")
     //adaugam un nou stil si o noua culoare literei //
     div.style.backgroundColor = randomColor
     // adaugam o pozitie literei //
     div.Style.top = top
     // pozitionam litera //
     div.Style.right = right
    // cream un element body // 
     document.querySelector("body").appendChild(div)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Need to replace

```
div.classlist.add("letter")
```

with

```
div.classList.add("letter")
```

The error is saying that whatever element you are trying to add to, on line 54, is undefined.

Looking at your code, it's either startbutton or div, those are the only elements that have "add" associated with it.

Can you post the full file so that we can see what's at line number 54?

Comment: You can just post it in the comment or edit the description to include the full Javascript. If you notice, your formatting is incorrect for the above code snippet. Try to edit that formatting so that all of the code is properly formatted and include the entire file, that way we can see exactly what's at each line.

Comment: https://www.udrop.com/4Vxy/speed.js does this help?

Comment: Looks like you have div.classlist instead of div.classList (note the "L" is capitalized)
div.classlist.add("letter") should be: div.classList.add("letter")

Comment: Another problem you're going to run into once you fix that is "color" is undefined, because your color variable is declared in the function createNewLetter() but you're attempting to access it outside of the function.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined
    at speed.js:56 that worked but now i get this error how i solve this?,i tried to give randomColor to that but it seems to not add an color still

Comment: That's the same problem as color, you're trying to access variables out of scope. The variables that you're trying to access are declared in the function createNewLetter, but aren't available outside of that function.

Comment: so i have to give a value to them all?

Comment: Yes. You can't call variables that are declared inside of a function outside of that function.

Comment: yeah but the problem is that i seem to get another error after i give an value so you got an better solution to make the program work?

Comment: Listen I'm happy to help you debug your code, but you need to take at least a few minutes to try to understand what might be causing the error instead of asking people to help you.

Try to figure it out for at least 10-15 minutes, then if you're still stuck, post your updated code, and I'll take a look.

Comment: hmm i seem to get stuck so i updated the code i tried giving value to top but that doesn't work and tried putting randomPosition instead but still same thing it seems,how i make the program work?

Comment: Listen, you're not trying enough before asking questions. I'm going to stop replying if you keep asking questions without trying to figure it out on your own. I went in and added randomPosition like this div.style.top = randomPosition(); and it works. So you obviously aren't trying very much troubleshooting. I'm here to help you not write the program for you. You're welcome by the way.

Comment: actually i  mostly don't get it that no  letter appears tho but thx tho,and as you can see i'm bad at debugging

Comment: If the function runs but nothing is showing up, then there are likely other issues. Try using your console, use console.log() to log elements to the console to see what Javascript is seeing for variables and calls. Use your inspector to inspect tags and ids of HTML elements. These are some things that will help you debug.

Comment: on your end does it do anything when you click the button startgame?,i tried doing console.log(letter) but i seem to get an undefined result

Comment: I don't have a button because you only provided me with the JS not the HTML. I think additional problems you're having would be in the scope of a new question.

Comment: snippet added can you test it now?